# html5 game object movement not working

Tags: html

I am trying to improve my html5 game that I am creating, I am trying to put player object movement into the game like so :

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        theplayer = function(width, height, color, x, y)
        {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.color = color;
            this.speedx = 0;
            this.speedy = 0;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;    

            this.update=function()
            {
                context.fillStyle = color;
                context.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
            }

            this.newpos=function()
            {
                this.x += this.speedx;
                this.y += this.speedy;
            }

        }

        var theplayer = new theplayer(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);

        function clearboard()
        {
            context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        }

        function movement()
        {
            document.addEventListener("keydown",keyPressed, false);
            document.addEventListener("keyup",keyLifted, false);
        }

        function keyPressed(event)
        {
            var keyPressed = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);

            if (keyPressed == "W")
            {       
                theplayer.speedx += 1;
            }
            else if (keyPressed == "D")
            {   
               theplayer.speedy += 1;
            }
            else if (keyPressed == "S")
            {   
               theplayer.speedx -= 1;   
            }
            else if (keyPressed == "A")
            {   
                theplayer.speedy -= 1;
            }
        }

        var rungame = setInterval(function()
        {
           clearboard();
           theplayer.newpos();
           theplayer.update();
        }, 20);
```

The program should make the player control the player object with the WASD keys but I am unable to make the change of X and Y coordinates apply to 'theplayer' object into the 'newpos' function. How can I solve the problem and is there anyway to put multiple key stroke presses of the WASD keys ?

Comment: Are you getting errors? What happens currently? Posting your code on plunker or other similar service might help us identify the issue.

Comment: @Mathieu de Lorimier [here is the demo - WASD to control](https://jsfiddle.net/gowhozard/p908t4vq/)

Comment: Your `movement`function never seems to be called thus never adding the keyboard event listener? Is it beeing called somewhere else?

Comment: @Mathieu de Lorimier May I know how could I make the movement function be called upon by the 'theplayer.newpos' function ?

Comment: Thet specific function should be called on document ready or something like that (so that the events listener are added only once). This is pretty basic stuff. I suggest you look at a JS tutorial on how to set event listeners.